Getting error "Error creating user TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create')" ,prisma+ express application
There is simple api in express

app.post("/api/addUserContact",async (req,res)=>{
 
console.log("tryign in the addUserContactInfo ")
  try{
const { formData } = await req.body;

 const { username, email, subject, message } = formData;
console.log(formData)
 const newUserQuery = await prisma.usercontact.create({
   data: {
     username: username,
     email: email,
     subject: subject,
     message: message,
   },
 })

 if (newUserQuery) {
   res.status(201).send("Created")
   console.log("User  contact query has been successfully created ")
 } else {
   console.log("usercontact query has been  is not created")
 }


  }catch(error){
      res.sendStatus(500)
      console.error("Error creating user", error)
    
    
  }
     


})

and this is my schema in schem.prisma ;
model Usercontact {

  id         Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  username   String   
  email  String                 
  subject String                
  message String         
   createdAt     DateTime  @default(now())       
}

I try to create User query from input from user and send it to backend api which should create Userquery .
But I am getting this error
and the line 89 is=
 const newUserQuery = await prisma.usercontact.create({

Error creating user TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create')
    at /opt/render/project/src/backend/index.js:89:48
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)


backend is deployed at render , if i run server at localhost than i am able to do "post" without facing any error , but if i use render domain for server than i am getting error , not on my loclhost server

It was build problem of render , and not code . So just deployed backend at another platform and now it's working fine .
The other possible error coudl be syntax error of model name in index.js like model name is User than while createing   we have to use prisma.user not prisma.User

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
